# Ansible: Select only part of the stdout

Tags: ansible

I have written a small playbook as below

## permissions.yaml

```
---
- hosts: centos

  tasks:
    - name: Set permissions
      find:
        paths: "/home/portaladmin/cq/author/crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default/"
        patterns: "*.tar"
      register: tar_files

    - debug: var=tar_files.files[0].path
```

I am fine with output here as

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "tar_files.files[0].path": "/home/portaladmin/cq/author/crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default/1.tar"
```

But I am actually having 10 tar files, as 1.tar to 10.tar. Is there any way we can get path of all the files from 1.tar to 10.tar.

I tried with `- debug: var=tar_files.files[0:].path` and `- debug: var=tar_files.files[0:4].path` but got error like no variable but with`- debug: var=tar_files.files[0-10].path` I got only one file named `1.tar` in the output.

Is there any way we can `1.tar` to `10.tar` complete paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
- debug: var=item.path
  with_items: "{{ tar_files.files }}"
```

You are not dealing with any stdout here, but Python objects. `tar_files` is a dictionary and `tar_files.files` is a list, so you should iterate over its elements.

Comment: No , this will print extra information also , not just only path. I tried this already. I just need only path for all results. Thanks for looking again.

Comment: This will print exactly and only the information you are asking for. Only the paths.

Comment: Yes my mistake , I didnt look at it. But may be its still looking for a list , look at this pastebin link https://pastebin.com/pYrhL8KA... This is the link with code and output https://pastebin.com/EUPEbjF1

Comment: Oh yeah substitution. Damn I am not thinking at all. But yeah this is 3rd question in a row answered by you. Thank you very much,

Comment: No its not working as expected. Its till printing total output along with item_path as well. https://pastebin.com/NYNTbs9R

Comment: Because that's how the debug module works. I'm not a fan of using debug for things other than debugging, and you did not ask a question about prettifying the log. You can search SO for solutions. There were questions about that already.

Comment: Learned something new though, Thank you very much,